# Faking a network outage inside codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have an integration test suite that runs in AWS codebuild. The program being tested is supposed to handle network outages by retrying operations, so I want to test that in the suite. Running locally, my test script fakes a network outage by using "route" to route all traffic that should go to the servers I use to loopback instead, activate my program, then after a few seconds remove those entries from the routing table and watch the failed commands succeed on a retry. Works great.

In AWS codebuild, when I run the "sudo route" command it fails with "SIOCADDRT: Operation not permitted". I know I can fake a network outage with iptables, so I tried "sudo iptables -L OUTPUT", and got a similar permission denied error.

Is there some way around this? Or is there another method to fake a network outage that will work in a codebuild container? I only need to block a few IP addresses.

AppSpec.yml:

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.9
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
          $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_PhastSchemaPackage/phastschema-1.0.0.tar.gz
          $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_PhastDevPackage/phastdev-1.0.0.tar.gz
  build:
    commands:
      - pycodestyle assayuploadertest
      - ( cd assayuploadertest ; pylint --disable=R0904,C0103,C0116,R0201,W0603,C0115,W9012,W9011,C0114,W1514 . )
      - ASSAY_UPLOADER_HOME=$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_AssayUploaderZip/src python -m unittest discover -s assayuploadertest
```

Comment: Can you not fake your API client somehow for the integration tests? Why are you changing the local system? Your integration tests shouldn't require manual intervention before and after running them, that defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The application under test is both a client (to other processes on the same system) and a server (to a cloud API). I'm trying to test behavior when the cloud API is unreachable. Letting the application run, while manipulating the network to create outages, seems to be standard integration test practices. Meanwhile, during the "network outage," the integration tests will submit request to the application. If all is well, once network is restored, the proper updates to the cloud system should be made.

Comment: So: are you spinning up the entire application in CodeBuild, testing and then spinning it back down? That’s functional testing if so, integration testing is much different. And they require different approaches hence me trying to clarify this.

Comment: It's a fairly fuzzy line between functional and integration test. In my experience functional testing was usually manual, while integration was usually automated. In any event, yes, you understand what I'm trying to do and I hope that codebuild has a way to fake a network outage; iptables and/or fiddling the routing table seemed easy but doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I understand - so are you spinning up the entire application in CodeBuild? Could you possibly share your `AppSpec` file?

Comment: Yes, entire application is spun up. Not sure why the AppSpec will be useful - it is quite dull! It just starts up the integration tests, which in their setUpClass function use Popen to start up the application under test.

Comment: Try running your commands without `sudo` i.e. `iptables` and `iptables -L OUTPUT`. What is the output?

Comment: Same result:
```
[Container] 2022/05/10 15:02:57 Running command iptables -L OUTPUT
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to AWS support if you're able to. Unless you find someone who has done this exact thing and get this in front of their eyes, they'll be your best bet 